# Magento 2.4.3 - The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again

Tags: database, magento2.4.3, store-id

when customers are trying to create a profile on our client's website they get the following error message:

"The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again."

After some troubleshooting, I think I found what the issue is, I noticed that the store id was 6 on the website and 5 on store view. I think this happened when we transferred this installation from one server to another.

Does anyone here know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is familiar to me.

You are right , the tables  or one of them are not  successfully transferred

[image]

You might also have other issues if you have  tables  in your database  starting with S or T U V W X Y Z
that tables might not be correctly imported too.

The fastest solution is to export the tables from the old server and import them into your new server.

The best solution is to check if your DB Dump was done correctly, then if not export it again and run the necessary part, if your DB is big you can dump only the tables You need to recover.

Comment: The problem we have is that the old server is not here anymore.... I do not think we can get the old DB now. Been too long.

Comment: In that case, you will need to carefully look at the issue and create tables and rows into them individually.

I can help you with this.